# AnnotationBbox not showing together with plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code snippet which I use to render a text box next to the plot:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnnotationBbox, TextArea

fig, ax = plt.subplots(layout="constrained")

f = np.array([2.15, 2.22, 2.3, 2.43, 2.54, 2.7, 2.79, 2.91, 3.04, 3.2, 3.29])
f_err = 0.01
d = np.array(
    [
        0.3393,
        0.3458,
        0.3622666666666667,
        0.38306666666666667,
        0.4004,
        0.429,
        0.43939999999999996,
        0.45239999999999997,
        0.481,
        0.5044,
        0.5174,
    ]
)
d_err = 0.0052

ax.errorbar(f, d, xerr=f_err, yerr=d_err, fmt=".", label="Measurements")

text_area = TextArea("Hello there!!!!!!")
text_box = AnnotationBbox(
    text_area, (1, 1), box_alignment=(0, 1), boxcoords="axes fraction"
)
ax.add_artist(text_box)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

In the past, I used the same code and it worked just fine as you can see:

[image]

However, running the snippet above makes the text box invisible:

[image]

Notice that it did create the space needed for the text (Changing the length of the text changes this space). However, the text itself doesn't appear. After debugging this, I found that commenting out the `errorbar` makes it work:

[image]

I can't understand why this happens. As I said before, I used the same code in the past and it worked fine. Can somebody explain why this happens and how I can fix this?